# No response available from custom Devise rails auth api, but my RABL api works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, angularjs

I'm using Restangular in AngularJS to connect to my RAILS API backend. I can grab data no problem using Restangular from my standard RABL api service, but when I try to POST to my custom Devise login/logout api controller O don't seem to get a resonse.

I followed this code ehere: 
http://lucatironi.github.io/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/

```
  def create
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged in",
                      :data => { :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token } }
  end
```

My first guess is that RABL is doing something right, where the render in the create method above isn't working for Restangular. I don't have a RABL template for the create method, do I need one?

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a before filter at the top of your controller to authenticate all methods by adding: `before_filter :authenticate_user!`.

If you'd rather do the authorisation in the method itself, just do `authenticate_user!`. I tried calling warden for authentication but I ended up running into many other problems.

For a RABL template, yes you need one.

Comment: Thanks, turns out rails expects parameters to be root wrapped (e.g. {user: {email: "email", password: "password"}} vs. just {email: "email", password: "password"}

Comment: or you can use JSON.parse :)